# Data memory bigger than resident memory as shown in htop

Tags: memory, htop, system-monitoring

I don't understand how the memory of processes is displayed in htop.
In almost all the processes the `M_DRS` (DATA) column shows a bigger value than the `M_RESIDENT` column.

According to the description in the setup, `M_RESIDENT` is the data section plus the text section plus the stack usage, while the `M_DRS` is the data section plus the stack usage.

So `M_RESIDENT` should be `M_DRS` plus the text section, that is `M_RESIDENT = M_DRS + M_TRS`, which implies that  `M_DRS < M_RESIDENT`, **But** it is not actually the case, since in most processes I get  exactly the opposite: `M_DRS > M_RESIDENT`.

Can explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

When application asks kernel for memory (using `mmap` syscall) kernel creates memory section (which you can see in `/proc/[pid]/mmaps`) but kernel doesn't have to use real physical RAM for that seciton.

First, no data was loaded there (yet), why waste physical memory?
Second, data may be swapped out.

So:

`M_DRS` is a sum of all memory sections not necessarily loaded into physical memory.

`M_RESIDENT` is what we have in physical RAM.

Lets have experiment:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
 char* foo = malloc(1024 * 1024 * 1024); // Ask kernel for 1GB !

 for(size_t i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024 * 1024; i += 1024 * 1024 * 10) {
 memset(foo + i, 'Q', 1024 * 1024 * 100); // Load 100MB 
 sleep(2); // Sleep for a while
 }
}
```

When you run this program, you should see DATA=1GB but RES is much smaller, but grows every 2 seconds.

This description is oversimplified, if you really interested, you should read something like "Understanding Linux Kernel"

See also https://darkcoding.net/software/resident-and-virtual-memory-on-linux-a-short-example/